# ADF: Comma disappears in pipeline Copy Actvitity, despite it's a string

Tags: postgresql, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in ADF with a Copy Activity. I am pushing my data to a Postgresql database. I have in my dataset a 'Total Costs' columns as a string. However, after running the pipeline the comma is not visible in this column in postgresql. What is going wrong? The goal is to convert this column in postgres back to a decimal number (if that matters).

[image: Total Cost column from the source]

[image: Mapping in ADF Copy Activity]

[image: Mapping in the pipeline JSON]

[image: Data in Postgresql]

Comment: Check that data type on the Postgresql table. It's probably some kind of numeric, even though ADF thinks its a string.

Comment: @ChenHirsh the data type of the column is integer says Postgres. So we can't go from 5508 as we see now to 55,08.

Comment: This is just for show. You can use a formatting function on your query in PostgreSQL to show the values as you want. for example: https://database.guide/format-numbers-with-commas-in-postgresql/

Answer (score 0):

> after running the pipeline, the comma is not visible in this column in postgresql.

Agreed with @Chen Hirsh the issue is with the data type of the particular column in PostgreSQL. If it is of numeric data type and ADF thinks it's a string it will not show you the `,` .

- To get the values with coma you can change the datatype of column to varchar (255) from Integer using below query in Pre-Copy script in ADF.

```sql
ALTER  TABLE Table_name ALTER  COLUMN  Column_name  TYPE  VARCHAR(255);
```

- You can use below a [formatting function](https://database.guide/format-numbers-with-commas-in-postgresql/#:%7E:text=In%20PostgreSQL,%20we%20can%20use,value%20using%20the%20current%20locale.) on your query in PostgreSQL to show the values with comma `,`

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(123456.78, 'FM99,99,99');
```

Comment: The formatting function won't work since I have numbers like 55,08 displayed as 5508, but also numbers like -212,4 displayed as -2124. So we don't know where to put the comma.

Comment: check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/MOfxwQx.png) it is what you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. I understand that TO_CHAR(-2124, 'FM99,99,99') is giving -21,24 as output, but unfortunately the original value is -212,4 which I should get. The numeric template pattern will work obviously for 5508 which should be 55,08 but not for -2124 which should be -212,4.

Comment: For this you need to save the data in varchar data type only as you don't have fixed patterns for all the values.